# I want to show post details based on roles user login

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles

I have a custom post type called `support`  I also have two roles: `manager` and `employee`.

Now I want to show post details based on roles. plz help me out.

custom post code

```
// supports

add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_support' );

function register_cpt_support() {

  $labels = array(
      'name' => __( 'support', 'support' ),
      'singular_name' => __( 'support', 'support' ),
      'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'support' ),
      'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New support', 'support' ),
      'edit_item' => __( 'Edit support', 'support' ),
      'new_item' => __( 'New support', 'support' ),
      'view_item' => __( 'View support', 'support' ),
      'search_items' => __( 'Search support', 'support' ),
      'not_found' => __( 'No support found', 'support' ),
      'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No support found in Trash', 'support' ),
      'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent support:', 'support' ),
      'menu_name' => __( 'support', 'support' ),
  );

  $args = array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'hierarchical' => false,
      'supports' => array( 'title','editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
      'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'page-category' ),
      'public' => true,
      'show_ui' => true,
  'show_in_menu' => true,
  'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-businessman',
      'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
      'exclude_from_search' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'query_var' => true,
      'can_export' => true,
  'rewrite' => true,
//   'show_in_rest' => true,
      'capability_type' => 'post'
  );

  register_post_type( 'support', $args );
}
```

front end code

```
 <div class="work">
                <div class="work-wrap">

                <h2>FAQ Articles…</h2>
    <ul class="clearfix item-list">
    <?php query_posts('category_name=home&post_type=support&posts_per_page=-1&order=ASC'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
                $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
                $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'', true); 
                ?>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><li class="work-box">
      <img src="<?php echo $image_url[0]; ?>" alt="y1" style="max-width:100%;" />
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
      </li></a>
      <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="btn more-trigger">View more articles...</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in your front end code.

```
<?php 
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $is_manager = in_array('manager', $user->roles);
?>
<?php if($is_manager): ?>
    <div>insert manager only content here</div>
<?php else: ?>
    <div>insert employee content here</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: now for testing i have 2  user roles but i have requirement of n number of user roles in production. so i need to display dynamic data based on roles of user. please help me out.